# How to set a default custom preset for linter-jscs to use with Atom Editor?

Tags: atom-editor, jscs

Using [linter-jscs](https://atom.io/packages/linter-jscs) for Atom Editor, is there a way to set a default custom jscs preset for all projects?

After reading the [docs](http://jscs.info/overview#options), I tried editing the file .atom/packages/linter-jscs/.jscsrc with the following code but it seemed to be ignored:

```
{
    "preset": "./custom.json"
}
```

Were can I define the custom configuration file?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Ok, I understand that the "preset:" configuration should be done in config.cson. But still, I can't get to point to a json file in the same directory as config.cson